# VBA Run-Time Error '1004' while using .formula

Tags: excel, vba

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2:B1000")) Is Nothing Then
Range(Target.Offset(0, 3).Address).Formula = "=If(" & Target.Offset(0,   1).Address & ">0,VLOOKUP(" & Target.Address & ",Sheet2!$B$1:$M$263,7,0),"")"
```

End If
End Sub

Comment: `",Sheet2!$B$1:$M$263,7,0),"""")"`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm a novice and had been stuck on that for a while, that is huge

Comment: Note that you can just use `Target.Offset(0, 3).Formula = ...`. `Target` is a `Range`.

Comment: Also `Target.Worksheet` can be replaced with `Me`.